# CSS not loading because of div in Visual Studio MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, razor, model-view-controller

I'm using visual studio 2013 MVC and I have my _Layout which has a template, all the scripts are loaded in my view Index and in my _layout I have a navbar, the navbar is supposed to have a messages dropdown menu that uses a lot of css and js.

When I load the messages as a partial view everything works, but when I try to use JQuery to reload the data on its own, I have to put it inside a div. Doing so breaks all the style like there was no Css, I have also tried just changing the id of a parent div and that also breaks the style. I'm using AdminLTE 2.

Examples:

when it is like this, it works

```
<li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
  <!-- Menu toggle button -->
  @Html.Action("Notifications", "Home")
</li>
```

just changing it to this breaks the style

```
<li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
  <!-- Menu toggle button -->
  <div>
    @Html.Action("Notifications", "Home")
  </div>
</li>
```

Additionally this is how I'm reloading that part

```
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    refreshNotifications();
  }

  function refreshNotifications() {
    console.log("Reload...");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'Home/Notifications',
      type: 'get',

      success: function(result) {
        //$("#partialsgpthing").html(result);

        // $("#navbar").html(result);
      }
  });

  setTimeout('refreshNotifications()', 30000);
}
</script>
```

And I'm using `public PartialViewResult Notifications()` in my controller

and the partial view is this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
    <span class="label label-warning">@ViewBag.Notifications</span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="header">Tiene @ViewBag.Notifications notificaciones</li>
    <li>
        <!-- Inner Menu: contains the notifications -->
        <ul class="menu" style=" max-height: 200px; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; overflow-x: hidden;">
            @foreach (string notification in ViewBag.NotificationMsgs) {
            <li>
                @{string[] detail = notification.Split('|');}

                <!-- start notification -->

                <a href="@detail[8]">
                    <i class="fa @detail[3] @detail[4]"></i> @detail[5]<br />@detail[2]
                </a>
            </li>
            }
            <!-- end notification -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="footer"><a href="#">Ver todas</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to make the style work or use a different method to reload constantly that part? Mainly anything that doesn't use a div will work I think.

I am loading the data from database so that's why it must pass through the controller.

on _layout I placed just the `<body>` of the adminlte, then on the main area for the page I placed the `@renderbody()` which renders the index. the index contains the  of the Adminlte template and most scripts

Comment: i am not sure if i get your question right, but normally you can't use a block (div,a, etc.) element inside a inline element, except you change the block element into a inline element via css :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With styles

```
<style type="text/css">
    .dropdown {font-size:2em;} 
    .notifications-menu {color:red;} 
    .dropdown div, .notifications-menu div {font-weight:bold;}
</style>
```

and list items

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
        <!-- Menu toggle button -->
        @Html.Action("Notifications", "Home") 
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
        <!-- Menu toggle button -->
        <div>
            @Html.Action("Notifications", "Home")
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I see no difference in effects of styles delivered by class selectors .dropdown or .notifications-menu, and additional specificity to div elements also works as expected. How are your style selectors declared?

Comment: They are all declared inthe CSS that came with the template

bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
 bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css
dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css
dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css
dist/css/skins/skin-green.min.css
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic

Comment: What are the styles that incorporate .dropdown or .notifications-menu in their selectors? Not in what files are they declared - what are the values?